# how do i get more information from a cmake failure in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

android studio 2021.2.1 on win10pro

i just moved to a new machine, and just did a "git clone" to pull my project.  when i try to build it i get the error message below.

it appears cmake is failing, but there is no indication of WHY it is failing.  i looked at all the various files and paths handed to cmake, and they all appear to exist.

how do i get cmake to give me more information about what has gone wrong?

[CXX1405] error when building with cmake using C:\Users\Gorilla\github\sunclock\sunclock1\app\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt: Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Gorilla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {-HC:\Users\Gorilla\github\sunclock\sunclock1\app\src\main\cpp -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=26 -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-26 -DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a -DANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Gorilla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=C:\Users\Gorilla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\Gorilla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.4.7075529\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\Gorilla\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.18.1\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Gorilla\github\sunclock\sunclock1\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\14685u17\obj\arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Gorilla\github\sunclock\sunclock1\app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\14685u17\obj\arm64-v8a -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -BC:\Users\Gorilla\github\sunclock\sunclock1\app.cxx\Debug\14685u17\arm64-v8a -GNinja}

Comment: opening a command prompt and entering the command gave me a "vcruntime140. dll not found" error.  i'm installing visual studio now, to see if that helps.

Comment: yep, that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

opening a command prompt and entering the command gave me a "vcruntime140.dll not found" error. installing visual studio fixed the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34582065)

Comment: totally answers the question @YaMiN